# Why is requestCode returned in onRequestPermissionsResult is 1 after user has granted runtime permissions?

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime-permissions

I have to get Runtime permissions from users. I'm passing requestCode as **200** in **ActivityCompat.requestPermissions** as you can see in code below.

But when the permissions are granted by the user, on **onRequestPermissionsResult**, the **requestCode** returned is **1**.  Here the **requestCode** returned should be **200**, right ?

Can anyone explain why the requestCode returned is **1** in **onRequestPermissionsResult** and not **200** (the code I'm pasisng to requestPermissions) after the user has granted/accepted the runtime permissions?

```
        var mRuntimePermissions = RuntimePermissions(permissions, this)
        var gotPermissions = mRuntimePermissions.hasPermissions()

        if(gotPermissions == true){

            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        }
        else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 200);
        }


override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                 permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {

            // check requestCode and do something

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are calling `requestPermission` from Fragment or Activity ? Post your full Activity code.

Comment: I'm calling from an Activity. This is the full activity code - https://pastebin.com/4SSNLvxP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not know how much it will help you; as it is not in `kotlin`. But i have implemented it in many projects in following manner.. Hope it helps you to get at least some clues.

Class declarations :

```
private static String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS};
public int ALL_PERMISSIONS = 0;
public boolean CheckNoPermission = false;
```

Now in OnCreate :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
    ALL_PERMISSIONS  = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    ALL_PERMISSIONS  = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS);

    // its below marshmallow
    // no need to ask permissions in this case
    // do the things here directly

    // START YOUR ACTIVITY HERE....
}
else
{
    // its marshmallow or above
    // have to ask permissions in this case

    // lets check if user already allowed the permissions in previous run

    for(int x = 0; x < PERMISSIONS.length; x++)
    {
        String ThisPermission = PERMISSIONS[x];

        if (checkSelfPermission(ThisPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
             CheckNoPermission = true;
             break;
        }
    }

    // even if any permission is not granted then re-request all permissions; 
    // re-requesting all permissions will only request denied permissions only

    if(CheckNoPermission)
    {
          // request all permissions one by one in array

          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, ALL_PERMISSIONS);
    }
    else
    {
         // user has already granted all the permissions in previous run
         // do the things here directly

         // START YOUR ACTIVITY HERE....
    }


}
```

Now check permissions result outside of onCreate :

```
// if permissions are requested; check for user approvals :

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length == 2)
    {
        Boolean IsAllPermissions = true;

        // Yes need to check all permissions again as user may have denied any of the permission

        for(int p = 0; p < grantResults.length; p++)
        {
            if (grantResults[p] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                IsAllPermissions = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(IsAllPermissions)
        {
            // user has granted all the permissions in this run
            // do the things here ...

            // START YOUR ACTIVITY HERE....
        }
        else
        {
            // user has not granted all the permissions in this run
            // so do what you want to do here in such case ...
        }
     }
     else
     {
         // missmatch in number of permissions in result
     }
 }
```

Android documentation on onRequestPermissionsResult [Is explained here...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback)
Hope it helps you or someone else

The synopsis of `onRequestPermissionsResult` :

1. `requestCode` is not for to pay attention on; its for application level
2. `permissions` is the array of all permissions requested by this requestCode
3. `grantResults` is an array of whatever user has done with the each and every single permission we have requested with this requestCode

requestCode is nothing to check for nor it has anything we have to do with

Comment: I understood your code but my question is different. I'm asking why the requestCode returned is 1 in onRequestPermissionsResult after the user has granted the prmissions and why the requestCode returned is not the same requestCode that we pass while asking for permission ?

Comment: @Gissipi_453, Within onRequestPermissionsResult we are supposed to cross check what user has done with the bunch of permissions... and requestCode is not for the same which you are thinking; Android could not detect "if all permissions are granted or not" withing sinle variable it just presents you its array... Its developers task to cross check if all permissions are GRANTED or NOT?

Comment: @Gissipi_453, Even android can not detect is it above marshmallow or not, developer need to program and handle all the possible cases with all the possible exceptions too

Comment: @Gissipi_453, requestCode is just for application level for android os to verify origin of the requests, permissions is the array of all permissions requested by this requestCode, grantResults is an array of whatever user has done with the each and every single permission we have requested with this requestCode.   requestCode is nothing to check for nor it has anything we have to do with...

Comment: thanks. that last comment answers my question. You can put this comment as part of the answer as well.

Comment: @Gissipi_453, Its my pleasure it helped you, in pseudo code wise too..!! Certainly i am editing again so that other users may find it helpful.

Answer (score -1):

We can send(Execute) the multiple `startActivity` from `activity's`  for result and in `onActivityForResult` method will receive multiple callbacks, so to identify the callback is for which request, that can be identified with `requestCode`, In-directly we can say `requestCode` as in id of the request that help us  handle the response in `onActivityResult`  method for particular request(`staryActivityForResult`).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. See my question and see the particular scenario I'm referring to.

Comment: Okay will try to come up with better approach for you :)